# Prometheus increase not handling process restarts

Tags: monitoring, metrics, prometheus

I am trying to figure out the behavior of Prometheus' *increase()* querying function with process restarts.

When there is a process restart within a 2m interval and I query:

```
sum(increase(my_metric_total[2m]))
```

I get a value less than expected.

For example, in a simple experiment I mock:

- 3 *lcm_restarts*
- 1 process restart
- 2 *lcm_restarts*

All within a 2 minute interval.

Upon querying:

```
sum(increase(lcm_restarts[2m]))
```

I receive a value of ~4.5 when I am expecting 5.

[lcm_restarts graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPm3i.png)

[sum(increase(lcm_restarts[2m])) result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ERIu.png)

Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty concise and well-prepared first question here. Please keep this spirit!

When working with counters, functions as `rate()`, `irate()` and also `increase()` are adjusting on resets due to restarts. Other than the name suggests, the `increase()` function does not calculate the absolute increase in the given time frame but is a different way to write `rate(metric[interval]) * number_of_seconds_in_interval`. The `rate()` function takes the first and the last measurement in a series and calculates the per-second increase in the given time. This is the reason why you may observe non-integer increases even if you always increase in full numbers as the measurements are almost never exactly at the start and end of the interval.

For more details about this, please have a look at the [prometheus docs for the `increase()` function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase()). There are also some good hints on what and what not to do when working with counters in the [robust perception blog](https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate).

Having a look at your label dimensions, I also think that counter resets don't apply to your constructed example. There is one label called `reason` that changed between the restarts and so created a second time series (not continuing the existing one). Here you are also basically summing up the rates of two different time series increases that (for themselves) both have their extrapolation happening.

So basically there isn't really anything wrong what you are doing, you just shouldn't rely on getting highly precise numbers out of prometheus for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus may return unexpected results from `increase()` function due to the following reasons:

- Prometheus may return fractional results from `increase()` over integer counter because of extrapolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details.
- Prometheus may return lower than expected results from `increase(m[d])` because it doesn't take into account possible counter increase between the last raw sample just before the specified lookbehind window `[d]` and the first raw sample inside the lookbehind window `[d]`. See [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) and [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) for details.
- Prometheus skips the increase for the first sample in a time series. For example, `increase()` over the following series of samples would return 1 instead of 11: `10 11 11`. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#avoid-missing-metrics) for details.

These issues are going to be fixed according to [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit). In the mean time it is possible to use other Prometheus-like systems such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/), which are free from these issues.